# Customize Error Message When Permission Check Fails

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The DRF documentation provides clear instructions on [how to create a custom permission](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions), offering the following code sample:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class BlacklistPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
"""
Global permission check for blacklisted IPs.
"""

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ip_addr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        blacklisted = Blacklist.objects.filter(ip_addr=ip_addr).exists()
        return not blacklisted
```

By default this gives the following response when the permission check function return `False`.

> HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Vary: Accept
>   Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
>
> {
>       "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
>   }

I would like to change the "detail" section above, offering a more developer-friendly error message. How could I do this, ensuring the message is presented each time the permission check fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Class `APIView` checks permissions via](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/4248a8d3fc725d9ae3fe7aaaad7ee12479ab07ab/rest_framework/views.py#L294)

```
def check_permissions(self, request):
    """
    Check if the request should be permitted.
    Raises an appropriate exception if the request is not permitted.
    """
    for permission in self.get_permissions():
        if not permission.has_permission(request, self):
            self.permission_denied(request)
```

And [here's `permission_denied`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/4248a8d3fc725d9ae3fe7aaaad7ee12479ab07ab/rest_framework/views.py#L143)

```
def permission_denied(self, request):
    """
    If request is not permitted, determine what kind of exception to raise.
    """
    if not request.successful_authenticator:
        raise exceptions.NotAuthenticated()
    raise exceptions.PermissionDenied()
```

So it seems entirely reasonable to subclass `exceptions.PermissionDenied` and raise it directly in your custom Permission class, eg

```
class CustomForbidden(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
    default_detail = "Add your custom error message here"


class CustomPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not_allowed:
            raise CustomForbidden
```

Comment: Is there a way I may force a custom message in Django on missing permission (instead of the `HTTP 403 Forbidden`)?

Answer (score 3):

For anybody from Google. There is now easier way to provide custom message. Just add attribute `message` to your custom permission class. [Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)

```py
class CustomPermission(BasePermission):
    message = 'My custom message'
```